# Why do people use i18n() and i18nc() instead of qsTr()?

Tags: localization, qml, kde-plasma

I'm completely new to translating QML widgets. 
I see people using i18n() and i18nc() in their source code.
I've found the commands documented here:

https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Localization/i18n#QML

But the QML documentation only lists the qsTr() method. I guess the other 2 commands are KDE specific?

Do I really have to dabble with those KDeclarative etc objects, in C++? I'm not really sure how that works. My widget doesn't use any of that, just qml files and some javascript files for external functions.

I've found out I can get the translation to work with PoEdit but only for .js files, if I define a custom source keyword (function name) to extract from them, but ONLY if they are i18n and i18nc (qsTr doesn't work) and when using a directory structure I stole from a working widget (that is /contents/locale/language_key/plasma_applet_*widget_id*.mo). Sadly, since the parser getText can't read qml files, this solution isn't good enough.

Now, I know qt provides a command, lupdate, to extract those keywords from the source, but that only works for qsTr, conversely. Trying to pass -tr-function-alias qsTr=(i18n) as an argument doesn't work. With qsTr() I can have a nice .ts file, but trying to convert that to po and use the previously mentioned trick doesn't work.

I wonder though, why the devs of the downloadable widgets all seem to use i18n and i18nc in their source code if lupdate doesn't seem to be able to extract those keywords.

Comment: i18n() and i18nc() are indeed KDE specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do people use i18n and i18nc instead of qsTr?
Probably because it's way more convenient. I've been able to get .qml files to work using the above-mentioned trick by simply manually editing the .po files (referencing the qml file in question, the line where the keyword occurs and so on).